# Im using Django as Backend and Reactjs as Frontend, So what must i use to route the urls

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-router, django-urls

What must i use for routing urls?
Using React-Router or Urls from Django?

ReactJS Route:

```
<Router>
<Route path="/" exact component={StatefullComponent} />
<Route path="/blog" exact component={BlogPost} />
<Route path="/blog/detail/:id" component={DetailPost} />
</Router>
```

Django Route(Urls):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
]
```

Question:
1.Which route is better?
2.Can i use both route for my urls?
3.If i use django urls, my frontend will using single page route like react did?

Comment: 1. depends on your project's need, 2. Yes, 3. Yes

Comment: thanks for your reply,
if i want to use both
how can i combine it?

Comment: It's better to use React router to determine which page to load because it's faster, but you also need to use Django's URL to serve your React application. Both of them are required. Let's assume you want to see blog detail and handle blog detail in front, How can you say to Django which page detail you want to load? So you also need to use Django router.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer ReactJS handle the routing, where using django to serve the react. So I prefer using the following pattern in django:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^.*$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='react_template_name.html')),
]
```

In this pattern, url accepts any path and servers ReactJs app in that. Then `React Router` takes over and does the rest of the routing.